# Combining generic methods and overloads

Tags: c#, generics, methods, types, overloading

I have the following method:

```
public void Set<T>(IEnumerable<T> records)
{
     foreach (var record in records)
     {
        Set(record);
     }
 }
```

I would like either one of the following `Set` methods to be called, depending on `T`:

```
    public void Set(RecordType1 record)
    {
        // Some RecordType1 logic
    }

    public void Set(RecordType2 record)
    {
        // Some logic applicable to RecordType2 only
    }
```

Hopefully, you can see that I'm attempting allow which `Set` method to called to be inferred at runtime. This "isn't working" (i.e. won't compile as it's expecting `RecordType1`).

**Question**

How can I keep this kind of structure without testing for a type before sending the records off to the `Set` method?

Answer (score 13):

Why don't you create an interface (`IRecordType`), allow `RecordType1` and `RecordType2` to inherit it, then move the main logic of each `Set` method to the interface.

```
public interface IRecordType
{
    void Set(...);
}
public void Set(IEnumerable<IRecordType> records)
{
    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        record.Set(...);
    }
}
```

This is a more maintainable solution. And it also allows for better polymorphism.

Edit: Resource to look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b5b8ezk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Also, little sidebar: with `interface`s you can not only share certain methods, but properties and events, as well. If `RecordType1` and `RecordType2` share several common properties, you can add those properties to the `interface`, and then use `IRecordType` wherever you would have previously needed to distinguish between the two for use of these properties, methods or events. Likewise, the code inside any of those properties, methods or events **is** permitted to rely on other properties, methods, events or fields that are specific to the object itself. This is the purpose of Object-Oriented languages (**C#**) and polymorphism.

Edit: As a result of the discussion in the comments, I also wanted to add more information about the decision between using an OOP approach (`interface`, `abstract class`, `class`) and the `dynamic` approach StriplingWarrior suggested:

If you don't have access to the actual implementation details of `RecordType1` or `RecordType2`, or you are unable to alter the design of your application (due to the impeding reliance on the `Set(RecordType1)` and `Set(RecordType2)` methods, you may find it more fruitful to take his approach of using `dynamic`. There are also other options out there that we may not have thought of - you could always give one of them a go. The downside to the `dynamic` approach is that it requires .NET 4.0.

Also, more considerations: if you do have access to `RecordType1` and `RecordType2` implementation details, but cannot change `Set(RecordType1)` and `Set(RecordType2)` as far as definition, you could always modify the body of them:

```
public void Set(RecordType1 record)
{
    record.Set(...);
}

public void Set(RecordType2 record)
{
    record.Set(...);
}
```

This preserves the **ENTIRE** application structure, while also decreasing code maintenance and allowing for polymorphism.

Comment: Your answer and OP's code are very different. OP didn't call `Set` method in `T` but the current class. Not sure why this is heavily upvoted :\

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I know, the OP's method is also not a good example of Object-Orientation. My solution is to provide the OP with a more maintainable project in the end, not just an answer to his question, but a solution to a more under-lying problem.

Comment: That's not always possible(if types belong to third parties). We need to use adapter pattern or some other kind in that case. However, I like your answer. +1 :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Indeed, which is why my answer is not always the correct answer. (As I mentioned in StriplingWarrior's answer, in a comment.) The path the OP takes is totally up to him - if he finds the OOP pattern to be more fruitful, he should take full advantage of it. That is the purpose of OOP languages like **C#**. But I do appreciate the critique - discussions like these are what inspire people to learn and research. I added more clarification to my answer, and will add even more shortly. :)

Comment: I agree with @SriramSakthivel here. I'm not upvoting you because what you describe is not a direct answer to the question, but a redesign of his application. I am of the opinion that answers should first and foremost answer the question directly, and then elaborate on other possible solutions to the problem as a side note. StriplingWarrior's post is a much better "answer" than yours in that respect. Keep in mind I do not disagree with what you said in the slightest (I think it's all valuable information, just not the answer to the question).

Comment: All is well, except that **bold** everywhere in your answer makes me sad. I didn't read that just because it is unnecessarily bold (I'm serious, I didn't read that part). Please remove it.

Comment: I think you may need to address the case where OP can't change his design as well. Then only this answer becomes a complete one.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I added way more clarification - I also removed an excessive amount of that **bolded** information. I think this discussion is great - it definitely shows the merits/downfalls of using either approach. The approach by StriplingWarrior demonstrates effective use of `dynamic`, but also allows for potential errors. It is also `.NET 4.0` reliant. As such, *may not* be the best option, depending on requirements.

Comment: @julealgon Yes, that is one of the unfortunate downfalls of my approach, the application requires extensive redesign. Cases such as that merit that StriplingWarrior's approach to be the most optimal. Or other cases that compare the `typeof` each object. Those cases, however, do not meet the requirements of the OP: that is, the decision is at runtime.

Answer (score 7):

If you're *positive* that every item in the given collection will match a method signature, you can cast the values as `dynamic` and let the runtime figure out what to bind it to:

```
 foreach (var record in records)
 {
    Set((dynamic)record);
 }
```

However, this is *highly error prone*, and I'd recommend you take a hard look at what you're really trying to accomplish. There's most likely a better pattern to accommodate your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated. Always interested to see where `dynamic` can sit in my code. Your answer is spot on, but as EBrown has indicated - there's obviously a floor in how I'm approaching this overall.

Comment: @DeeMac Not necessarily, there are times when this solution is ideal over the one I provided, you need to take the following considerations: if the code in the `Set` methods does not describe a manipulation of the `object` itself, you should likely use this method. However, I suspect that your `Set` method heavily describes a manipulation of the object itself, and as such it should be inside the object it is manipulating.

Comment: @DeeMac Also, as SriramSakthivel suggested in the comments on my answer: if you do not have access to the source code for `RecordType1` or `RecordType2`, you are somewhat better off with this method, as it does not require the adjustment/modification of the object definitions themselves.